# How do I set path in oozie workflows?

Tags: shell, hadoop, workflow, hdfs, oozie

I am trying to run a Shell Script on Oozie.First, I selected the path of shell script file, after which I added the arguments to run the shell script file. When I try running the oozie worflow, as such, it goes into a running loop which gets killed after 10 seconds.

I also added the Environment Variable by setting the path of the output folder in HDFS. When I run it, again it runs into a loop which gets killed after 10 seconds. I am unable to figure out how to set the path. Please help.

Comment: Perhaps you can edit your question to include the actual commands you run than simply describe them.  Also you could post relevant snippets from any logs. See stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, 
But I gess , your are trying to run Shell Script using Oozie workflow, where Shell Script Arguments will be pass  from Oozie it self.

If My understanding is right, you can pass the Argument variable from Oozie  via coordinator.properties/coordinator.xml/workflow.xml it self.

Example:
let say You have a shell script, which will perform distcp everytime its execute to anothere dfs location.

Shell Script:

```
> hadoop dfs -rmr destination_location
> hadoop distcp hdfs://<source_dfs><source_dfs_location> hdfs://<destination_dfs><destination_dfs_location>

workflow.xml:



 <action name="shellAction">
        <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                  <name>oozie.launcher.mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                  <value>default</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
            <exec>shell_script.sh</exec>
                        <file>hdfs://<dfs:port>/<dfs_location/shell_script.sh></file>
            <capture-output/>
        </shell>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="killAction"/>
    </action>
         <kill name="killAction">
               <message>Shell Action Failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
     </kill>
```

Note: Shell action chould be defined in oozie_site.xml
Belive these will help u some point